# javascript course online, problems with task

Tags: javascript

I am complete beginner in javascript, well and programming in general. The task given in online course is pretty complicated for me.

Basically, it is called checks.js (because it suppose to check your index work) suppose to work like this:

```
// Built-in  Node.JS module for the check
var assert = require('assert');

// input your function
var addTime = require('./index.js');

assert.equal(addTime(12, 30, 30), '13:00', 'when 30 min is added to 12:30 we get 13:00');
assert.equal(addTime(23, 59, 31), '00:30', 'when 31 min is added to 23:59 we get 00:30');
assert.equal(addTime(11, 50, 61), '12:51', 'when 61 min is added to 11:50 we get 12:51');
assert.equal(addTime(23, 1, 80), '00:21', 'when 80 min is added to 23:01 we get 00:21');

console.info('OK!');
```

'index.js' is made by a student, the template is like this:

```
/**
 * @param {Number} hours
 * @param {Number} minutes
 * @param {Number} interval
 * @returns {String}
 */
module.exports = function (hours, minutes, interval) {

};
```

So I have been made index like this:

```
module.exports = function (hours, minutes, interval) {
    var allmin = (hours * 60)+minutes+interval;
    var allhours = Math.floor(allmin / 60);
    var fMin = allmin % 60

    if (allhours < 10) {
        allhours = toString(allhours);
        allhours = '0'+allhours;
    }

    if (fMin < 10) {
        fMin = toString(fMin); 
        fMin = '0'+fMin;
    }
    return allhours+':'+fMin
}
```

And the second one like this:

```
module.exports = function (hours, minutes, interval) {

   if (hours < 0 || hours > 23) {return false}
    var hours = Math.floor((minutes + interval) / 60);
    var minutes = (minutes + interval) % 60;

    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = toString(hours);
        hours = '0'+hours;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = toString(minutes); 
        minutes = '0'+minutes;
    }

    return (hours+':'+minutes);
}
```

which is pretty much the same, but when i run checks.js in terminal to check my index.js, I constantly getting an error:

```
MBP-John-2:coursera JJ$ node checks.js
assert.js:86
  throw new AssertionError(obj);
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: При добавлении 30 мин. к 12:30 получится 13:00
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/JJ/js_playground/coursera/checks.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:308:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:878:3)
MBP-John-2:coursera JJ$
```

Really need help!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The error comes from the fact that your code does not return what the assertion expects. Just call the function you've developed (without the asserts), for example: `addTime(12, 30, 30) `, you will see that the result is not `13:00`.

Comment: Just helping you debugging it: you cannot call `toString(something)`, what you should do is `something.toString()`.